# install on Intel i3-4130 system

Tags: 14.04

I am installing Ubuntu 14.04 on a system with an Intel i3-4130 processor and a Intel C226 Chip-set,with Intel HD graphics 4400 card and coprocessor. I am looking for drivers to support it. Thank you for any help.

Comment: You should not need to find any additional drivers other than those built into Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

The Intel HD 4400 is supported by the i915 driver that is part of the official Ubuntu kernel. You don't need anything special.